# in QML How to show dynamic model in qt quick

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qml

I have a model that show some select from several tables.this is my modal.h code :

```
Q_PROPERTY(QStringList userRoleNames READ userRoleNames CONSTANT)


public:

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QString queryStr() const;
    void setQueryStr(const QString &query1);
    QStringList userRoleNames() const;

    //=====================================
    //         QUERYs
    //=====================================
    void listAllCars();
    void listPersonel(int opid);
    Q_INVOKABLE void listStayCars(int opid);
```

and this is my cpp code:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> DynamicModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    for (int i = 0; i < record().count(); i ++) {
        roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + i + 1, record().fieldName(i).toUtf8());
    }
    return roles;
}

QVariant DynamicModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QVariant value;
    if (index.isValid()) {
        if (role < Qt::UserRole) {
            value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
        } else {
            int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
            QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
            value = QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
        }
    }
    return value;
}


void DynamicModel::setQueryStr(const QString &query1){
//    if(queryStr() == query)
//        return;
//    setQuery(query);

this->setQuery(query1,QSqlDatabase::database("MainDB"));
qDebug()<<query().lastQuery();
qDebug()<<query().lastError();
qDebug()<<this->rowCount();
    emit queryStrChanged();
}

QStringList DynamicModel::userRoleNames() const {
    QStringList names;
    for (int i = 0; i < record().count(); i ++) {
        names << record().fieldName(i).toUtf8();
    }
    return names;
}

void DynamicModel::listAllCars()
{
    QString str;
    str.append("SELECT * from IORecord where Date1=date('now');");
    this->setQuery(str,QSqlDatabase::database("MainDB"));
    setQueryStr(str);
    qDebug()<<query().lastQuery();
    qDebug()<<query().lastError();
    qDebug()<<this->rowCount();
}

void DynamicModel::listPersonel(int opid)
{
    QString str;
    str.append("SELECT * from Personel");
    str.append(" ;");
    this->setQuery(str,QSqlDatabase::database("MainDB"));
    qDebug()<<query().lastQuery();
    qDebug()<<query().lastError();
    qDebug()<<this->rowCount();
}

void DynamicModel::listStayCars(int opid)
{
    QString str;
    str.append("SELECT Date1 ,EnterTime,Date2 ,ExitTime,CalculateFee ,AcceptedFee ,Description  "
               "from IORecord where UserID=");
    str.append(QString::number(opid));
    str.append(" ;");
    this->setQuery(str,QSqlDatabase::database("MainDB"));

    qDebug()<<query().lastQuery();
    qDebug()<<query().lastError();
    qDebug()<<this->rowCount();
}
```

i want to show every query ,that i need, to the user.
I used this QML :

```
Component{
        id: lblComponent
        Label{}
    }

ListView{
    id: view
    property int id: 1
    x:30
    y:30
    width: 500
    height: 500
    model: sqlmodel
    delegate: Row {
        id:myrow
        spacing: 10
        width: parent.width
        height: 20
        Component.onCompleted: {
            var roleList = sqlmodel.userRoleNames
            var temp = []
            for(var i in roleList){
                var role  = roleList[i]
                var lbl = lblComponent.createObject(myrow,{ text : role});

                //myrow.push(columnComponent.createObject(view, { "role": role, "title": role}))
            }

        }}
```

How can I show this model to user? how to show this dynamic model in list view? how can I define delegate when I don't know how many label I should use? I just have rolename .

Comment: its better to share your qml code which you are into desing to see what you mean

Comment: I edited. thanx. I used this QML to load my data. but just repeat the name of role not the value

Comment: Is there any help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a tough one.

My suggestion would be to get rid of the ListView and use a TableView (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html) instead.

This way, you have a variable number of columns (fields, which you request with your query) as well as a variable number of rows (your records).

Your basic ListView is very configurable, that's true, but it reaches its limits, when you only determine at run-time what fields you want to show or - more important - how many.

Thinking about it while typing, you could define a widget type in C++ code, which takes the responsibility of displaying the record and expose that type to QML to be created as delegate for the ListView. If you call `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()` when you perform you DB request, new delegates will be created to display the new content, so you could configure the exposed factory function for the delegate with the fields of your query.

Well, easiest is the TableView, I guess. If you need to have it beautiful, you might need to opt for a more complicated version, like creating a custom widget type.